# Using inactive memory to my advantage. What is this code storing in RAM or inactive memory?

Tags: memory, memory-management, file-io

I'm developing on OS X 10.8.3. The following code is simple. It can perform two operations. If the read function is uncommented then the program will open the file at "address" and transfer all of its contents into data. If instead, the memcpy function is uncommented the program will copy the mmapped contents into data. I am developing on a mac which caches commonly used files in inactive memory of RAM for faster future access. I have turned off caching in both the file control and mmap becuase I am working with large files of 1 GB or greater. If i did not setup the NOCACHE option, the entire 1 GB would be stored in inactive memory.

If the read function is uncommented, the program behaves as expected. Nothing is cached and everytime the program is ran it takes about 20 seconds to read the entire 1 GB.

But if instead the memcpy function is uncommented something changes. Still i see no increase in memory and it still takes 20 seconds to copy on the first run. But every execution after the previous one, copies in under a second. This is very analogous to the behavior of caching the entire file in inactive memory, but I never see an increase in memory. Even if I then do not mmap the file and only perform a read, it performs in the same time, under a second.

Something must be getting stored in inactive memory, but what and how do I track it? I would like to find what is being stored and use it to my advantage.

I am using activity monitor to see a general memory size. I am using Xcode Instruments to compare the initial memcpy execution to an execution where both read and memcpy are commented. I see no difference in the Allocations, File Activity, Reads/Writes, VM Tracker, or Shared Memory tools.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    unsigned char     *data;
    unsigned char     *mmapdata;
    size_t            length;

    int file = open("address", O_RDONLY);
    fcntl(file, F_NOCACHE, 1);

    struct stat st;
    stat("address", &st);
    length = st.st_size;

    data = malloc(length);
    memset(data,0,length);

    mmapdata = mmap(NULL, length, PROT_READ,MAP_SHARED|MAP_NOCACHE, file, 0);
    if (mmapdata == MAP_FAILED)
        fprintf(stderr, "failure");

//    read(file,data,length);
    close(file);

//    memcpy(data,mmapdata,length);
    munmap(mmapdata,length);

    free(data);

    return 0;
}
```

UPDATE:

Sorry if I was unclear. During program execution, the active memory portion of my RAM increases according to the data I malloc and the size of the mmapped file. This is surely where the pages are residing. After cleanup, the amount of available memory returns to as it was before. Inactive memory is never increased. It makes sense that the OS wouldn't really throw that active memory away since free memory is useless, but this process is not identical to caching, because of the following reason. I've tested two scenarios. In both I load a number of files who's size totals more than my available ram. One scenario I cache the files and one I do not. With caching, my inactive memory increases and once I fill my ram everything slows down tremendously. Loading a new file will replace another file's allocated inactive memory but this process will take an exceptionally longer time than the next scenario. The next scenario is with caching off. I again run the program several times loading enough files to fill my ram, but inactive memory never increases and active memory always returns to normal so it appears I've done nothing. The files I've mmapped still load fast, just as before, but mmapping new files load in a normal amount of time, replacing other files. My system never slows down with this method. Why is the second scenario faster?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How could the OS possibly make a `memcpy` on an `mmap`'d file work if the file's pages weren't resident in memory? The OS takes your hint that you don't want the data cached, but if still will if it has no choice or it has nothing better to do with the memory.

Your pages have the lowest priority, because the OS believes you that you won't access them again. But they had to be resident for the `memcpy` to work, and the OS won't throw them away just to have free memory (which is 100% useless). Inactive memory is better than free memory because there's at least some chance it might save I/O operations.

Comment: I added an update to the end of my question. It was too long to add as a comment.

Comment: Update: The second scenario is faster because the memory you are using is at a lower priority and so doesn't kick data that is reused out of cache.